# Differential equation related

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $$y =x\log\frac{x}{{a+bx}}, $$ then prove that  $$x^3y'' =(xy' - y)^2.$$

I don't have any idea.

Please help me.

Comment: Those are first and second differentiation of y respectively

Comment: Take the first and second derivatives of $y$ and try to relate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $y=x\log x-x\log(a+bx)$. Differentiate both sides, you get
$$y'=\log x+1-\log(a+bx)-\frac{bx}{a+bx}$$
Multiplay both sides by $x$ and compare with the original equation,
\begin{equation}
xy'=y+x-\frac{bx^2}{a+bx}=y+\frac{ax}{a+bx}
\end{equation}
Differentiate both sides again,
$$y'+xy''=y'+\frac{a^2}{(a+bx)^2}$$
Then, you have 
$$x^3y''=\cfrac{a^2x^2}{(a+bx)^2}$$
Now, go back to the second step, and substract both sides by $y$, you get
$$xy'-y=\frac{ax}{a+bx}$$
Square it, and you are done.